# Querying M:M relationships using Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework, .net-4.0

How would I modify the following code:

```
    var result = from p in Cache.Model.Products
                 from f in p.Flavours
                 where f.FlavourID == "012541-5-5-5-651"
                 select p;
```

So that `f.FlavourID` is supplied a range of ID's as a supposed to just one value as shown in the above example?

Given the following ERD Model:

Products* => **ProdCombinations** <= *Flavours

ProdCombinations is a junction/link table and simply has one composite key in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the top of my head

```
string [] ids = new[]{"012541-5-5-5-651", "012541-5-5-5-652", "012541-5-5-5-653"};

var result = from p in Cache.Model.Products
                 from f in p.Flavours
                 where ids.Contains(f.FlavourID)
                 select p;
```

There are some limitations, but an array of ids has worked for me before. I've only actually tried with SQL Server backend, and my IDs were integers.

As I understand it, Linq needs to translate your query into SQL, and it's only possible sometimes. For example it's not possible with `IEnumerable<SomeClass>`, which produces a runtime error, but possible with a collection of simple types.

Comment: Any `IEnumerable<int>` is actually possible. Non-primitive types are a problem though - like `IEnumerable<SomeClass>`.

Comment: Aha, I'll adjust my answer then.